# Intellij : Geb page object pattern navigation

Tags: intellij-idea, geb, pageobjects

While developing Geb script in IntelliJ it's very hard to navigate to page object method, So every time it required to open that page and serach for method.

For example:

```groovy
Class LoginPage extends Page {
  static at = { waitFor("slow")  { title == "Login Page" }}
    static content = {
        txtUsername                         {$("#txtUserName")}
        txtPassword                         {$("#pwd")}
        btnLogin        (required:false)    {$("#Login")}
    }

   def login(String userName, String pwd){
      // ...
   }
}
```

```groovy
class LoginSpec extends GebSpec {
    def "verify logic scenario" {
        given: 'Username and Password'
            def username = "abc"
            def password = "jdaafafjadfgajffaghfg"
        when: 'Fire Login URL'
            to LoginPage
        and: 'Enter Valid username,password and click on Login button'
            login(username, password)
        then: 'It should successfully and redirect to homepage'
            at HomePage
    } 

    // ...
}
```

Here it's not easy to navigate to login method with one click.

Do we have any plugin or setting to make easy this navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the cursor on the page class name and just press `Ctrl-B` or use `Ctrl-LeftMouse` in order to get there. As for easier navigation and code completion, I suggest assigning the result of `to MyPage` to a variable and then use that variable for calling page methods, e.g.

```groovy
class LoginSpec extends GebSpec {
  def "verify logic scenario" {
    given: "user name and password"
    def username = "abc"
    def password = "jdaafafjadfgajffaghfg"

    when: "opening login page"
    def loginPage = to LoginPage

    and: "logging it with valid credentials"
    loginPage.login(username, password)

    then: "after successful login the user gets redirected to the homepage"
    at HomePage
  } 
}
```

Now `Ctrl-B` and `Ctrl-LeftMouse` should also work for your method calls and page element references such as `loginPage.txtUsername`.